# GitHub XCRUN Error Between Xcode and Eclipse

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, xcode, github

I use both Xcode and Eclipse. I have an Eclipse project that I pull from GitHub, and when I am trying to pull this project I am getting a message that says `xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use xcode-select to change`

Any idea what's going on here? I am trying to pull to my Eclipse project but am getting this error that is talking about Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Ran `sudo xcode-select --reset` in the terminal, it seemed the clear the issue and I was able to use GitHub normally.